# Residual structure in Linear Mixed Models with Random effects

Tags: r, mixed-model

You can further improve a linear mixed model with random intercept and slope by specifying a structure in the residuals (for example AR(1)).

In SAS it is possible, but I hope this is also already possible in R. Does somebody knows how to do this?

I am using both packages lme4 and nlme.

Thank you,
Kasper

Comment: It is possible in `nlme`. Check the use of `?corARMA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the book "*Linear mixed effect models using R*" by the authors Andrezej Galecki and Tomasz Burzykowski, I could not find a way to do it in R.

However, one example in the book Applied "*Longitudinal Data Analysis*" by Fitzmaurice, Laird and Ware apply this methodology, and on their website, they give the R code:

> model2 <- lme(pbf ~ time + time0, random= ~ 1 | id,
>   +    corr=corCAR1(, form= ~ time | id))

The full script you can find on:

http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/

Comment: I would say the canonical reference on the ``nlme`` package is [Pinheiro & Bates (2000)](http://www.amazon.com/Mixed-Effects-Models-S-PLUS-Statistics-Computing/dp/1441903178/). They are, after all, the authors of that package. And in that book, they give plenty of examples illustrating the use residual correlation structures.